# Add multiple values to one field - VisualForce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, salesforce-id

I have a simple visual force page with a form on a SF site.  I have a pageBlockTable on the form. I would like to be able to add skill1, skill2, skill, all to the Job_tag__c field.

Here's what I attempted to do:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Job__c}" var="a" styleClass="table" title="skill"  id="table" >

    <apex:column headerValue="Skill 1">
        <apex:inputField value="{!a.Job_Tag__c}"/>
    </apex:column> 

    <apex:column headerValue="Skill 2">
        <apex:inputField value="{!a.Job_Tag__c}"/>
    </apex:column> 

    <apex:column headerValue="Skill 3">
        <apex:inputField value="{!a.Job_Tag__c}"/>
    </apex:column>   

</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

It's just passing the last value entered to the form.  Any ideas how I can get the all the tags to populate the field job tag?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I build a multi-select picklist UI in visualforce?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1264/how-do-i-build-a-multi-select-picklist-ui-in-visualforce)

Comment: @gato, it's not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish.  What is the data type of the Job_Tag__c field -- is it a multipicklist, text, or something else?  What is the user experience you're trying to provide?

Comment: It's a text field.  Trying to allow the user to have more than one input field to add job tags instead of grouping them all into one field.  It's for a form, and I'm trying to make it a easy as posible for the user to separate tags.   Looking at it again, I should just group them into one.  The multi-select would be ok, but they're predefined values.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this question on [multi-select picklist UI components in Salesforce.](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1264/how-do-i-build-a-multi-select-picklist-ui-in-visualforce)

It points you to this [post](http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2012/06/a-multiselect-picklist-visualforce-component.html) by Pat Patterson that should help.