# Code check - is there a better way Multi-select account names in VF

Tags: visualforce, multi-select

I have been tweaking an online example I found to meet my needs - it works, but I'm curious if there is a better way. Basically I have tweak a static multi-select to call Account names.

```
public with sharing class demo_multiselectcls {

// Test string
// Set<String> originalvalues = new Set<String>{'A','B','C','D','E','F','G'};

Set<String> firmvalues;
Set<String> originalvalues;  

String accvalues = FirmNames();

 Public List<string> leftselected{get;set;}    
 Public List<string> rightselected{get;set;}    
 Set<string> leftvalues = new Set<string>();    
 Set<string> rightvalues = new Set<string>();


public String FirmNames(){ 

    firmvalues = new Set<String>();

    List<Account> accts =[select Name from Account]; 
    for (Account a:accts){

        firmvalues.add(a.Name);
    }

    originalvalues = firmvalues;

    return   null;  

}

 public demo_multiselectcls(){        

    leftselected = new List<String>();        
    rightselected = new List<String>();        
    leftvalues.addAll(originalvalues);     
 }         

 public PageReference selectclick(){        
    rightselected.clear();        

        for(String s : leftselected){            

            leftvalues.remove(s);            
            rightvalues.add(s);        
        }        
 return null;    
 }        

 public PageReference unselectclick(){        

    leftselected.clear();

    for(String s : rightselected){            
    rightvalues.remove(s);            
    leftvalues.add(s);        
    }        
  return null;    
  } 

  public List<SelectOption> getunSelectedValues(){        

    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();        
    List<string> tempList = new List<String>();        
    tempList.addAll(leftvalues);        
    tempList.sort();        

        for(string s : tempList)            
            options.add(new SelectOption(s,s));        
            return options;    
  }     

  public List<SelectOption> getSelectedValues(){        

  List<SelectOption> options1 = new List<SelectOption>();        
  List<string> tempList = new List<String>();        
  tempList.addAll(rightvalues);        
  tempList.sort();        

    for(String s : tempList)            
        options1.add(new SelectOption(s,s));        
        return options1;    
  }
```

}

Comment: I have created the method FirmNames, it works but doesn't seem right. Thanks

Comment: have you looked at the http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1264/how-do-i-build-a-multi-select-picklist-ui-in-visualforce/1265#1265  this is exactly what metadaddy blessed us with

Answer (score 1):

Thanks metadaddy - your solution fits perfectly

http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2012/06/a-multiselect-picklist-visualforce-component.html